# PDF-Plumber Extracting title if metadata is not present

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have used pdf plumber to extract the text out of pdf files as per the GitHub page (https://github.com/jsvine/pdfplumber) I went through all properties, I need to extract the title of the pdf if the metadata is not present.

**or any other way  we can achieve this using python**

```
import pdfplumber
pdf = pdfplumber.open(r'1.pdf')
page = pdf.pages[0]
text = page.extract_text()
print(page.chars[0])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the below approach

```
import pdfplumber
pdf = pdfplumber.open(r'1.pdf')
page = pdf.pages[0]

filtered = page.filter(lambda x: x.get("size", 0) > 20)
filtered.extract_text()
```